# Datatable in not updating after successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I'm deleting row from datatable , and then after deleting record , I'm binding table row again then calling `dataTable` function again but it is not updating the total number of record showing at bottom . 
from server side I'm getting updated number of record , and also in my table updated number of row. but total number shown by dataTable is not updated.
this is my ajax code

```
 $(document).delegate('.Delete', 'click', function () {
            var getDeleteID = parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').find('span').text());

            BootstrapDialog.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete person?', function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        url: '/Home/DeleteData',
                        data: { Id: getDeleteID },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            BindTable(data);

                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert("Error In Deleting Person ");
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
        });
    });
```

this is my BindTable Function

```
  function BindTable(data) {

        var tabHtml = '';
        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
            tabHtml += "<tr><td><span class='hide'>" + d.ID + "</span>" + d.Name + "</td><td>" + d.Position + "</td><td>" + d.Age + "</td><td>" + d.Salary + "</td><td><span class='Edit ML10'>Edit</span><span class='Delete ML10'>Delete</span> </tr>";
        });
        $('#dbTable').find('tbody').html(tabHtml);
        $('#dbTable').dataTable();
    }
```

HTML :

```
<table id="dbTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Position
            </th>
            <th>
                Age
            </th>
            <th>
                Salary
            </th>
            <th>
                Action
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184530/datatables-reload-on-change-event

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: not working .

Comment: check console for any errors of ks

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I checked . There is no error.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I checked, MyEach loop is iterat Properly , It showing  one less record too but dataTable showing Total Number is wrong.

Comment: put table in a container div and append complete table in that div in success call and then destory and reninitialize datatable

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: i did like this
`$('#dbTable').find('tbody').html(tabHtml);
        $('#dbTable').dataTable().fnDestroy();
        $('#dbTable').dataTable();`
but still not working.